# How to get back the forgotten widget placed in grid using grid_remove back into active state?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I have the below piece of code:
a. Where it has two radio buttons.
b. clicking one of the button, removes the other radio button using `grid_remove()`.
c. And then it adds up label and entry widget.
d. And then I tried to do `dictionary['element'].grid()` to get back the removed widget, but I don't see it getting placed back again.

```
#!/usr/intel/bin/python2.7

import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *

class simpleapp_tk(Tkinter.Tk):

def __init__(self,parent):
    Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
    self.parent = parent

    self.entries = {}
    self.sc_button = None
    self.cv_button = None
    self.scl1 = None 
    self.sce1 = None
    self.scl2 = None

    self.initialize()

def initialize(self):
    self.grid()

    initial_screen_buttons = (
     ('self.sc_button', 'Single Component','v', 1, self.singlecomponent, 4, 'W'),
     ('self.cv_button', 'Comple Component','v', 2, self.complecomponent, 5, 'W')
    )

    #entries = []
    for _ButtonName , _Text, _Variable, _Value, _Operation, _Row, _Sticky in initial_screen_buttons: 
        _ButtonName_tmp = Radiobutton(self, anchor="center", text=_Text, variable=_Variable, value=_Value, command=_Operation)
        _ButtonName_tmp.grid(row=_Row, sticky=_Sticky)
        _ButtonName_tmp.rowconfigure(_Row,weight=1)
        self.entries[_ButtonName] =_ButtonName_tmp
        print 'Name of the button is ', _ButtonName
        print 'Name of the button is ', _ButtonName_tmp

    self.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
    self.grid_columnconfigure(1,weight=1)
    self.grid_columnconfigure(2,weight=1)
    self.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
    self.grid_rowconfigure(1,weight=1)

def singlecomponent(self):
    #self.cv_button.grid_forget()
    print 'Values in entries', self.entries
    print 'Values in entries', self.entries["self.cv_button"]
    self.entries['self.cv_button'].grid_remove()
    #self.entries[1].grid_forget()

    # print "value of v is %d"%v.get()

    if not (self.scl1):
        self.scl1 = Label(self, text="Enter The Widget Name You Wanted To Create: ")
        self.scl1.grid(row=6)

    if not (self.sce1): 
        self.sce1 = Entry(self)
        self.sce1.grid(row=7)

    if not (self.scl2):
        self.scl2 = Label(self, text="Which Widget You Wanted To Create: ")
        self.scl2.grid(row=8)

    self.entries['self.cv_button'].grid() #Calling the grid back is not getting placed back again.

def complecomponent(self):
    #self.sc_button.grid_forget()
    print 'Values in entries', self.entries['self.sc_button']
    self.entries['self.sc_button'].grid_forget()
    #self.entries[0].grid_forget()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = simpleapp_tk(None)
    app.title("Test App")
    app.mainloop()
```

Queries:
a. Won't Calling the grid() get back the already removed widget using grid_remove()?
b. Or is there any better solution to get back the widget?

Can anyone comment/suggest what needs to be done ?

Comment: In your code, clicking the 'Single Component' radiobutton, removes and puts back the `self.cv_button` in the same function, which means you will not see it being removed. Clicking 'Comple Component' does remove the `self.sc_button` because you only call `grid_forget`. So what did you expect te code to do?

Comment: Hard to follow your code, but  `grid()` will display any widget removed by `grid_remove()`

Comment: @fhdrsdg: But when I click the single component radiobutton, I do see that self.cv_button is getting removed, then it adds the label, entry, and again a label below the single component radio button. But I don't see the self.cv_button getting added back again as I expected because I tried using .grid() to place it back.

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ: But I explicitly used self.entries['self.cv_button'].grid() expecting that it will display the comple component radio button widget which was removed using grid_remove().

Comment: @Vimo That's weird. Copy-pasting and running this exact code and clicking the 'Single Component' button give me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qb5p8.png). Do you see something different? If so, what OS and what IDE do you use?

Comment: @Vimo Also, if you actually want to keep seeing the button, why do you remove it and put it back? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @fhdrsdg: Had some issue with respect to my repositories and have mixed with pack & grid caused the issue. It's working fine now.

Comment: Between which is a better coding options:
a. Either to using grid_remove(), so that system keeps track of the components in its memory ?
b. Or use grid_forget() and re-create when its required so that you free up the memory ?

Comment: I'd say that depends on whether you want to put the widget back at the same place or not. If you're going to put it back in the same place, I would use `grid_remove` to make it remember it's placement. If you're going to put it at a different place, there's no use in remembering the location, so you can use `grid_forget`.